# Javascript .load

Tags: javascript, html

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, у меня есть многостраничный сайт, разные страницы естественно имеют свою иерархию, подключая стили я всегда пользовался ../../
Сейчас встал вопрос сделать popup, мелкими, так сказать, шажками:
Файл: Popup.js

```js
$(function() {
  $('.popup_buy').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    $('#popup').html(" ").load('popup.html').show();
    $('#back_side').toggleClass('black');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Этот код работает если открытый файл находится в той же директории, что и popup.html. Но у меня таких директорий огромная куча. Как мне прописать код, чтобы файл popup.html всегда подгружался из корня сайта?

Comment: `.load('/popup.html')`?

Comment: У меня разная иерархия, где-то 4 папки вверх, где-то 6, где-то 2, такой вариант не прокатывает.

Comment: И что? `/` это всегда ровно один и тот же корень, независимо от иерархии

Comment: Странно, изначально писал так, не работало, сейчас снова сделал - заработало... мистика... вроде бы не менял ничего )

Comment: @andreymal  может быть оформите как ответ?

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин хз, я слишком наугад ответил, лично для меня деталей в вопросе недостаточно чтоб я полноценный ответ писал